# Asymptytic behavior of $2^{f(n)-1}+g(n)$?

Tags: optimization, asymptotics, discrete-optimization

Let $\mathbb N^*$ denote the set of all positive integers. Can we choose functions $f,g:\mathbb N^*\to\mathbb N^*$ such that

1. $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{f(n)-1}+g(n)-\sqrt{2n}}{\sqrt n}}=0$ and
2. $n\leq\left(2^{f(n)}-1\right)g(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N^*$?

Note that if $f$ and $g$ are allowed to have real values, then the answer is yes, since we can choose $f(n)=\log_2\left(\sqrt{2n}+1\right)$ and $g(n)=\sqrt{\frac n2}$ (One can verify using Lagrange multipliers that these $f$ and $g$ are in fact optimal). But I do not know what to do when $f$ and $g$ are restricted to have only integer values.

Comment: Maybe something like (with your current $f$ and $g$) $\lceil f \rceil$ $\lfloor g \rfloor$ or other combinations of $f$, $g$ and the ceil or floor functions would work? These are just suggestions though.

Comment: @BrunoB. I just realized that, if I replace $\sqrt{2n}$ in Condition 1 by $(3/2)\sqrt n$, then the answer is yes: We can define $f(n)=\lfloor\log_2(\sqrt{2n}+1)\rceil$ and $g(n)=\lceil n/\left(2^{f(n)}-1\right)\rceil$. I think $3/2$ ($=1.500$) is the smallest constant. I doubt that it is still true for $\sqrt2$ ($\approx1.414$).